# Photoshop Script - Save layers and put into folders with same structure as groups

Tags: javascript, photoshop, layer, photoshop-script

I found an online script which saves each layer as a png/jpeg. It works perfectly, however it does not take photoshop groups into account. I've had a look online and I can't find anything of the sort.

Just to be clear I want to add the features to the script so it still saves each layer as a png but also places the layers into folders, in the same layout that they are in their groups in the application.

Here is the SaveLayers.jsx script I currently have:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uog82udqd6c2pwj/SaveLayers.jsx
```

Not sure if it's possible but thanks in advance.
By the way I have hardly any knowledge of javascript.

Comment: DropBox says, "The file you're looking for has been deleted or moved."

Comment: I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, and have come to a solution. for anyone who needs the script (may want to improve it because i'm a photoshop script noob) - I have come up with a solution to my problem, anyone who needs it - https://www.dropbox.com/s/krg392w8mpqnr2c/Save%20Layers%20and%20Put%20in%20Groups.js

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, and have come to a solution. for anyone who needs the script (may want to improve it because i'm a photoshop script noob) - I have come up with a solution to my problem, anyone who needs it - `https://www.dropbox.com/s/krg392w8mpqnr2c/Save%20Layers%20and%20Put%20in%20Groups.js`

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the original SaveLayers.jsx to include an option to use folder organization.
Here is my version:
https://github.com/slek120/Photoshop-Export-Layers-as-Images

There are a few other changes you can see in the commit comment.